# Why does selector '+' in css does not apply to image?

Tags: css

So I have a pretty basic CSS that say if you hover a button the image is displayed. But I don't get why it is not working. Is there a specification I don't get?

```css
#hoverMe:hover + img, #hoverMe:hover + p {
  background-color:red;
  display:block;
}
img {
  display:none;
  transition:0.5s;
}
```

```html
<button id="hoverMe">HOVER ME</button>
<p>Test</p>          
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x200" id="image2">
</div>
```

Comment: Also  transition on `display` doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

The `+` is the *adjacent sibling selector*. Your rule works on the `p` element because it's adjacent. The `div` isn't adjacent, and the `img` isn't even on the same level.

Instead you can use the general sibling selector `~` to get to the `div`, and then use regular nesting to select the `img`:

```css
#hoverMe:hover ~ div img, #hoverMe:hover + p {
  background-color:red;
  display:block;
}
img {
  display:none;
  transition:0.5s;
}
```

```html
<button id="hoverMe">HOVER ME</button>
<p>Test</p>          
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x200" id="image2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You selector needed some work. `+` means **sibling that immediately follows**.

```css
#hoverMe:hover + p + .image img, #hoverMe:hover + p {
  background-color:red;
  display:block;
}
img {
  display:none;
  transition:0.5s;
}
```

```html
<button id="hoverMe">HOVER ME</button>
<p>Test</p>          
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x200" id="image2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes:

`#hoverMe:hover ~ div,`

`.image {
      display:none;
      transition:0.5s;
    }`

- Since you have the `img` in a `div.image`,
- you should target the `div.image` since it's a sibling,
- but use `~` instead of `+`, because `div.image` is not next to `#hoverMe`,
- use `+` when the sibling is right next to `#hoverMe` like the `<p>`

```css
#hoverMe:hover ~ div, #hoverMe:hover + p {
  background-color:red;
  display:block;
}
.image {
  display:none;
  transition:0.5s;
}
```

```html
<button id="hoverMe">HOVER ME</button>
<p>Test</p>          
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x200" id="image2">
</div>
```